# What do we call functions satisfying $[a[b]c] = [abc]$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $M$ denote a monoid and suppose we're given a function $[-] : M \rightarrow M$ satisfying $[a[b]c] = [abc].$ Then:

> **Proposition 0.** $[-]$ is idempotent.

*Proof.* Take $a=c=1$).

> **Proposition 1.** The set of fixed points of $[-]$ becomes a monoid with identity $[1]$ and multiplication $a,b \mapsto [ab]$.

*Proof.*

Associativity: $[[ab]c] = [abc] = [a[bc]]$

Left-identity: $[[1]a] = [1a] = [a] = a$

Right-identity: $[a[1]] = [a1] = [a] = a$

> **Question.** What are functions satisfying this condition called?

I'm also interested in higher-categorical generalizations.

Comment: Do you have examples in mind?   E.g. [f]=f(0), [M]=det(M), [z]=|z|, [(x1,...xn)]=([x1],...[xn])?

Comment: Another example is the additive monoid of ideals of a commutative ring and the operation of taking the radical: We have $\displaystyle\sqrt{I+J} = \sqrt{I+\sqrt{J}}$. Prop 1 tells us that there is an additive monoid of radical ideals, where the "radical sum" of two radical ideals $I,J$ is $\sqrt{I+J}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple observation: The condition is equivalent to $$\forall a,b \in M. \, [a \cdot [b]]=[a \cdot  b]=[[a] \cdot  b].$$
Assume that $M$ is a preordered monoid. Then it is natural to assume $a \leq [a]$, and $a \mapsto [a]$ behaves like a "closure operator". The fixed points are the closed elements. There are lots of examples for this. This setting can be generalized and has been studied before:

Assume that $M$ is a monoidal category with underlying category $C$ and $R : C \to C$ is a functor equipped with a natural transformation $\eta : \mathrm{id}_C \to R$ (satisfying $R\eta=\eta R$). Then one may demand that the induced morphisms
$$R(a \otimes R(b)) \leftarrow R(a \otimes b)  \to R(R(a) \otimes b)$$
are isomorphisms. This situation appears in Day's [reflection theorem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404972900217) for closed monoidal categories; here the reflection is called **normal**. This is used to endow reflective subcategories of $C$ with a monoidal structure. It is also useful for the construction of monoidal localizations, see Day's [Note on monoidal localization](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700045433). I would also consult the papers which cite these.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another notion. Let ' be the operation of adding a unit to a monoid.  Let [] be its inverse, which is the identity, except the old and new unit map to the old unit.  This is another example of how things behave. This suggests to me that [] behaves well on congruences of the monoid, and that there may be some polynomial operations that can represent [].

Gerhard "Make This More Generally Algebraic" Paseman, 2016.12.29.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: The [] operation reminded me of some similar functions used in the beginnings of tame congruence theory (TCT), and a simple version of this in a monoid context is "undoing" an adjoined unit.  One can imagine an iterated version undoing a succession of adjoined units, and this suggested to me operations on congruence classes, which also appears in TCT. Rather than suggest "Find an answer in TCT" (I think you won't), I suggest "Look among congruence preserving polynomial operations", where you might find a name for your relation.  Gerhard "Can't Elaborate Too Much More" Paseman, 2016.12.29.